# How ignore null field for deserializing with Jackson and use default value?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

My `@RequestBody` class looks like that:

```
data class UpsertDataDto(
    @field:JsonProperty("pages")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    val links: List<Long> = emptyList()
)
```

I want to avoid error in case `null` for `links` field so I use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation and default value `emptyList()`. But when I send request with null, I get such exception:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.life.app.domain.dto.request.UpsertDataDto] 
value failed for JSON property links due to missing (therefore NULL) 
value for creator parameter synonyms which is a non-nullable type; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: 
Instantiation of [simple type, class com.life.app.domain.dto.request.UpsertDataDto] value 
failed for JSON property links due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter links 
which is a non-nullable type<EOL> at 
[Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 422, column: 1] 
(through reference chain: com.life.app.domain.dto.request.UpsertDataDto["pages"]->java.util.ArrayList[38]->
com.life.app.domain.dto.request.UpsertDataDto["links"])]
```

Json that I use for testing

```json
{
    "links": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately default values will never work with this. I've encountered similar issue with Gson but I asume Jackson works the same. it never calls the default constructors so default values are never applied. It creates instances of the data class using something called an `UnsafeAllocator`. A more thorough explanation for Gson can be read [here](https://programmerr47.medium.com/gson-unsafe-problem-d1ff29d4696f)

But fortunately in that article it mentions that Jackson has a solution for this. To quote:

> In Jackson there is a pretty good solution for such cases. It has two special annotations: @JsonCreator and @JsonProperty
>
> Here is an example how you can use them (link to article):
>
> ```
> public class NonDefaultBean {
>     private final String name;
>     private final int age;
>
>     private String type;
>
>     @JsonCreator
>     public NonDefaultBean(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("age") int age)
>     {
>         this.name = name;
>         this.age = age;
>     }
>
>     public void setType(String type) {
>         this.type = type;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In this case Unsafe will not be used. Instead of that bad approach (here example link, why is that) a normal constructor NonDefaultBean(String name, int age) will be invoked.

Although, this is a java example and it also isn't a data class. I'm not entirely sure if you can do the same in kotlin or if you maybe need to make it a normal class instead of a data class. But hopefully you can work it out.